# Yaml If blocks causes missing mapping

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to add an optional set of parameters when the build running is not on the master branch. The idea is that azure-pipelines-template-variables-private.yml overrides just some of the parameters contained in the group.

This is my template file:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: "Tests"
    variables:
      - group: MyLibrary
    ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
      - template: azure-pipelines-template-variables-private.yml
```

This returns the error "Expected a mapping"

Without the if block the behaviour is as expected - the parameters are overwritten. I'm struggling to understand how if blocks work. The docs show how to use variables with Group and variables with templates - but not both together. Though it seems to work together, so I would expect the if statement to work.

Edit: For information I'm including the variable template contents:

```yaml
variables:
  - name: MyVar1
    value: 'TEST-$(Build.BuildId)'
  - name: MyVar2
    value: '/Builds/$(BUILD.BUILDID)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the script below and it works well. Hope this helps you :

```yaml
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: run_build
        
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04' 
    variables:
    - group: xxx
    - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
      - template: var.yml
    steps:      
      - script: echo ${{ variables.test }}
```

Comment: Many thanks this works perfectly. I find the docs confusing. All the if block examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input do not say when to start with a hyphen and when not to. Or what the indentation should be. I'm sure it's some YAML standard I do not know about - but the docs would could be clearer.

Comment: I refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime) :)